# mac XAMPP Apache shuts down immediately

Tags: php, macos, apache, xampp

I've got a clean install of my macbook again, reinstalled the OS and just installed XAMPP. I've clicked "Start" on Apache, and just as the icon turns orange it turns red again.

I have tried:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

but that just returns the following:

> /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: Could not find specified service

~~~~~~~~~~~~

Then I tried

```
sudo apachectl stop
```

And that returned the following:

> /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: Could not find specified service

~~

Using the following starts it and works, though the MySQL doesnt work with it

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/apachectl start
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start
```

Though I don't want to go through the process of doing it through the terminal every single time.

[Gyazo gif of my situation](https://i.gyazo.com/c03b117b6463f27c48c2216b1a40739b.gif)

This is really frustrating because this is the 3rd time I've re-installed my OS (Had nothing to lose so I went on and did it)

Is it possible that it has invalid permissions?

Comment: Do you have something else running on port 80? Mac usually comes with a http server already installed.

Comment: What shows up in the Apache log?

Comment: Starting Apache Web Server...
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd started
And no, I don't have anything else running on port 80